# Highstock reading data X axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

Hi guys I need help with highstock. It reads data correctly for Yaxis but not for the Xaxis where it needs to show the date to use range selector. I used the debugger mode in my browser to see the difference between my data(array) and the one from the highstock example.

This is my data:

```
[Array[2] 0: "01/2013" 1: 1 length: 2...
```

and this is data from the highstock example:

```
0: Array[2]0: 1064361600000 1: 0.8709 length: 2
```

this array[0] is what I don't understand, it shows for this array Wednesday, Sep 24, 2003.

Highstock uses this weird number for the string where I use actual string but it won't show on my graph.

Any ideas?

Comment: This "weird" number is a timestamp in js format (milliseconds, not just seconds as in php) ;)

Comment: so what should I do to use my string in my graph? do I need to change my array or...?

Comment: Convert it by Date.parse() / use Date.UTC() or get data in correct form from your source.

Comment: @SebastianBochan thank you that is what I need it's just that my date has month and year in it and I see that Date.parse needs month, day and year. Is there any date parse that takes just month and year or should I just put day in it?

Comment: You can split string by / and use Date.UTC();